# I can't registrate more than one user in a devise session

Tags: authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Device to authenticate admins and users.
Admins can register users but, every time when an admin wants to register more than one user, the admin must destroy and create his admin session for ever user that he wants to register. i.e., the admin session allows registering only one user.

That's a successfull user(alunos) register right after admin login.

```
Started POST "/alunos" for ::1 at 2019-09-30 10:39:29 -0300
Processing by Alunos::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"WBl6StcQuSl+v/rCuvm/xUPp6u/Cpz137gHunvUtE1yWUXkwoCu5AvXYfKX1PfxhNoV3JtzluHK9P+uHb+LDyw==", "x"=>"31", "y"=>"25", "aluno"=>{"matricula"=>"M1", "nome"=>"AA", "rg"=>"11", "cpf"=>"11", "nascimento"=>"2001-01-01", "sexo"=>"Masculino", "estadocivil"=>"solteiro", "telefone"=>"11", "email"=>"test1@test", "cidade"=>"AA", "rua"=>"AA", "numero"=>"11", "bairro"=>"AA", "complemento"=>"AA", "estado"=>"AA", "pais"=>"AA", "cep"=>"AA", "naturalidade"=>"AA", "ingresso"=>"11", "turma"=>"AA", "conjuge"=>"AA", "mae"=>"AA", "pai"=>"AA", "igreja_id"=>"1", "residenocampus"=>"1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Aluno Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `alunos` WHERE `alunos`.`email` = BINARY 'test1@test' LIMIT 1
  Aluno Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `alunos` (`matricula`, `nome`, `rg`, `cpf`, `telefone`, `email`, `sexo`, `ingresso`, `turma`, `nascimento`, `cidade`, `igreja_id`, `estado`, `rua`, `bairro`, `complemento`, `cep`, `numero`, `pais`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `naturalidade`, `estadocivil`, `residenocampus`, `conjuge`, `mae`, `pai`, `encrypted_password`) VALUES ('M1', 'AA', '11', '11', '11', 'test1@test', 'Masculino', 11, 'AA', '2001-01-01', 'AA', 1, 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 11, 'AA', '2019-09-30 13:39:29.269375', '2019-09-30 13:39:29.269375', 'AA', 'solteiro', TRUE, 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', '$2a$11$jh1UODTYW40mnf2Tc.rJ/ubDhZWc3nH/qfc1CJeAOijDYccEBhXIy')
   (3.6ms)  COMMIT
```

And here's an unsuccessfull register right after the first register.

```
Started POST "/alunos" for ::1 at 2019-09-30 10:40:17 -0300
Processing by Alunos::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"0HM5IujlLKwLOVdfVEMi6zoYM2WDCNS3SWOZnLncnkkeOzpYn94sh4Be0Tgbh2FPT3SurJ1KUbIaXZyFIxNO3g==", "x"=>"16", "y"=>"19", "aluno"=>{"matricula"=>"BB", "nome"=>"BB", "rg"=>"22", "cpf"=>"22", "nascimento"=>"2001-01-02", "sexo"=>"Feminino", "estadocivil"=>"casado", "telefone"=>"22", "email"=>"test2@test", "cidade"=>"BB", "rua"=>"BB", "numero"=>"22", "bairro"=>"BB", "complemento"=>"BB", "estado"=>"BB", "pais"=>"BB", "cep"=>"BB", "naturalidade"=>"BB", "ingresso"=>"22", "turma"=>"BB", "conjuge"=>"BB", "mae"=>"BB", "pai"=>"BB", "igreja_id"=>"2", "residenocampus"=>"1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Aluno Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `alunos`.* FROM `alunos` WHERE `alunos`.`id` = 9 ORDER BY `alunos`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms | Allocations: 1819)
```

I realize that the error "Filter chain halted as require_no_authentication rendered or redirected" is the cause of that!

Can someone help me to solve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was simple to solve!

If someone have the same issue, I only block devise to try to login the just registrated user:

```
class Alunos::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
      super 
    end

    protected

    def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      true
    end
end
```